# How can I position the border bottom of a word to the bottom of its container?

Tags: html, css, jsx

I am trying to set the bottom border of these words in a navbar to the bottom of the container.

I have it working with the border appearing under the word when it is hovered, but I want the border to appear aligned to the bottom of the container instead of directly underneath (The words should to stay where they are, with a gap between the word and its border).  How can I do this?

Here is my JSX.

```
  <div className="navbar-container-b">
        <span>Today</span>
        <span>Hourly</span>
        <span>10 Day</span>
        <span>Weekend</span>
        <span>Monthly</span>
        <span>Radar</span>
        <span>Video</span>
        <span>More Forecasts</span>
      </div>
```

and CSS

```
.navbar-container-b {
  background-color: rgb(16, 32, 74);
  height: 20px;
  padding: 20px;
  color: white;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
}

.navbar-container-b span {
  cursor: pointer;

}

.navbar-container-b span:hover {
  border-bottom: 2px solid white;
}
```

Here is what it looks like when you hover over them https://i.stack.imgur.com/6kfE8.png, but I need the white border to align with the bottom of the dark blue container.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**To add a gap between the word and the border**, you can add padding to the bottom of the `span` with the word, e.g.

```
.navbar-container-b span {
    display:inline-block;  /* so we can add padding to the span */
    padding-bottom: 20px;  /* add the space between the word and border*/
}
```

**To make border appear at the bottom of the container:** The space you are seeing around these words is being added by the `padding:20px` you have on the `.navbar-container-b`. This is adding 20px to all sides, including the bottom.

If you change the `padding-bottom` to 0 and use `align-items: baseline;`, the text will sit exactly at the bottom. The changes you need for this are:

```
.navbar-container-b {
   padding: 20px 20px 0;
   height: 40px; /* add the extra 20px for the space between the word and border*/
   align-items: baseline;
   /* rest of your CSS*/
}
```

**Working Example:**

```css
.navbar-container-b {
  background-color: rgb(16, 32, 74);
  height: 40px;
  padding: 20px 20px 0;
  color: white;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: baseline;
}

.navbar-container-b span {
  cursor: pointer;
  display:inline-block;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
}

.navbar-container-b span:hover {
  border-bottom: 2px solid white;
}
```

```html
<div class="navbar-container-b">
        <span>Today</span>
        <span>Hourly</span>
        <span>10 Day</span>
        <span>Weekend</span>
        <span>Monthly</span>
        <span>Radar</span>
        <span>Video</span>
        <span>More Forecasts</span>
      </div>
```

Comment: Sorry, I guess i should have been more clear. I wanted the words to continue being where they are in the center of the container, but I want the border alone to sit at the bottom of the container is this possible? The baseline did help the jumping though I have never used that thank you

Comment: @Jayg713 So you mean to have a big gap between the word and its underline? Yes thats possible. Also, is the underline to appear only on hover (like your code) or always (like the image)?

Comment: Only when you hover, I just wanted to show what it looks like when you do hover. But yes, a big gap between the word and border

Comment: @Jayg713 I've updated my answer to do this - let me know if that is what you were looking for! (Also, you should update your question too so that it is still helpful to other users with the same question)

Comment: That makes perfect sense & yes exactly what I was looking for, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use align-items:flex-end since you already set the display to flex.

I also adjusted the height to 35px and the padding to 2.5px but you can play with these values to achieve the final desired layout.

```css
.navbar-container-b {
  background-color: rgb(16, 32, 74);
  height: 35px;
  padding: 2.5px;
  color: white;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: flex-end;
}

.navbar-container-b span {
  cursor: pointer;

}

.navbar-container-b span:hover {
  border-bottom: 2px solid white;
}
```

```html
 <div class="navbar-container-b">
        <span>Today</span>
        <span>Hourly</span>
        <span>10 Day</span>
        <span>Weekend</span>
        <span>Monthly</span>
        <span>Radar</span>
        <span>Video</span>
        <span>More Forecasts</span>
      </div>
```

Comment: You can play with it on codepen if you want: https://codepen.io/larrytherabbit/pen/qBZxKyG

Answer (score 0):

In this case the spans take 100% of the height of the parent and added the border with a before element.

This method will work with any height(I have set height to 100px but it will work with any value) on `.navbar-container-b` without changing paddings on other elements(span in this case)

```css
.navbar-container-b {
  background-color: rgb(16, 32, 74);
  /** original height 60px */
  height: 100px; 
  padding-left: 20px;
  padding-right: 20px;
  color: white;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
}

.navbar-container-b span {
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  position: relative;
}

.navbar-container-b span:hover:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 2px;
  background-color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="navbar-container-b">
  <span>Today</span>
  <span>Hourly</span>
  <span>10 Day</span>
  <span>Weekend</span>
  <span>Monthly</span>
  <span>Radar</span>
  <span>Video</span>
  <span>More Forecasts</span>
</div>
```